# Is there a way to reorder the category tabs in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, gmail-categories

Gmail presents its category tabs in the order *Primary*, *Social*, *Promotions*, *Updates*, *Forums*.

[image: An overview of the category tabs in Gmail]

I'd like to move *Promotions* to the end and move up *Updates* to the second position for my work e-mail, since that is where all automatic reports go, all notifications about new tickets, and so on.

**Can I reorder the tabs?**

Comment: I want exactly this.

Comment: I can't believe it's almost three years later and there is still no way to change this. Updates should come right after Primary, Promotions should come last, this is so reasonable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm afraid not. (At least, not at this time.) All you can do with the categories (beyond "Primary") is turn them on or off.

An option for you is to create a custom label for your work email and have those messages drop into "Primary". Easy enough to do with a filter.

Comment: Especially relevant now as it looks like they just moved the Promotions tab where the Social tab used to be, presumably to get some cheap mistaken clicks on that tab before people realize the change occurred. Pathetic.

Answer (score -5):

I precede tab names with a hashtag (#) to make them appear at the top of the list.  Also, you can simply number the tab names to make them appear in order.

Comment: My question is about the category-tabs at the top of the page. As far as I know, these can't be renamed. See the screenshot in the question. Are you sure you're talking about those too?